# C++: Stroustrup iterator_traits example not compiling?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to compile the code from Stroustrups C++ 4th Ed Page 124 and 125, section Iterator Traits.  Unfortunately, the compilation results in numerous errors which look like they are in the template system.  Does anyone know whats wrong with this code?

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <forward_list>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename Ran>
void sort_helper(Ran beg, Ran end, random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    sort(beg, end);
}

template<typename For>
void sort_helper(For beg, For end, forward_iterator_tag)
{
    vector<decltype(*beg)> v {beg, end};
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), beg); 
}

template<typename C>
using Iterator_type = typename C::iterator;

template<typename Iter>
using Iterator_category = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category;

template<typename C> void sort(C& c)
{
    using Iter = Iterator_type<C>; // ex. vector<int>::iterator
    sort_helper(c.begin(), c.end(), Iterator_category<Iter>{});
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    forward_list<int> fl = {2, 1, 0};
    vector<int> v = {2, 1, 0};

    sort(fl); // this line causes compilation error
    sort(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/string:41,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/ios:42,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/iostream:39,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'class __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int&>':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/allocator.h:116:11:   required from 'class std::allocator<int&>'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:87:21:   required from 'struct std::_Vector_base<int&, std::allocator<int&> >'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:389:11:   required from 'class std::vector<int&, std::allocator<int&> >'
<source>:17:28:   required from 'void sort_helper(For, For, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with For = std::_Fwd_list_iterator<int>]'
<source>:31:16:   required from 'void sort(C&) [with C = std::forward_list<int>]'
<source>:39:12:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/ext/new_allocator.h:62:26: error: forming pointer to reference type 'int&'
   62 |       typedef _Tp*       pointer;
      |                          ^~~~~~~
... and more ...
```

Comment: That's not an error, that's a _location_ of the error. Where's the rest of the message?

Comment: I know it can be difficult to find the important part of the error. What you included is only part of where the error is. The actual error is `error: forming pointer to reference type 'int&'`. When you are not sure, better include the complete error message

Comment: True.  Stackoverflow would only let me include so much code.

Comment: dont know what you mean. added the error from [here](https://godbolt.org/z/CZckkf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate a `vector<int>`, but doing

```
std::vector<decltype(*beg)>
```

gives a `std::vector<int&>`.

Instead you should use the `value_type` of the iterator:

```
std::vector<typename For::value_type> v {beg, end};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EdLadF).

Comment: This resolved this problem.  My question here is why must this be used instead of decltype(*beg) per Stroustrup's code?

Comment: @notaorb because you cannot have a vector of references

Answer (score 3):

This is a known error in the book.

From http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html:

> pg 125: `s/decltype(*beg)/Value_type<For>/` reparing the use of decltype would take more space than I have here.

Answer (score 2):

Within the function `sort_helper`

```
template<typename For>
void sort_helper(For beg, For end, forward_iterator_tag)
{
    vector<decltype(*beg)> v {beg, end};
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), beg); 
}
```

In this statement

```
vector<decltype(*beg)> v {beg, end};
```

the template argument is deduced like a referenced type. So in this statement there is declared a vector of references that is invalid.

Change this statement to

```
vector<std::decay_t<decltype( *beg )>> v {beg, end};
```

You will need to include the header `<type_traits>`.

Or you could explicitly to specify removing of reference like

```
vector<typename std::remove_reference<decltype( *beg )>::type> v {beg, end};
```

or

```
vector<typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype( *beg )>> v {beg, end};
```